# How to print lines from another class

Tags: java, class, events, printing, program-entry-point

**UPDATE** 
I was wrong the whole time. I was blocking the output with a method I was using and didn't add here. Now it works well and I'm able to write from other process.

I would like to know if there is any way of printing a line to a console view from outside. I have a class (class1) that has an onMessage method.

```
public class Class1 implements MessageListener {
    ...
    public void onMessage(Message msg) {
        System.out.println(msg.getText());
    }
    ...
}
```

And then I have a class with a main that creates an instance of this class and while doing things the onMessage of Class1 fires.

```
public class Class2{    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Class1 obj = new Class1();
        ...
        while(!":q".equals((action = scanner.next()))){
            obj.anotherAction(action);
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

When I try that the object seems to be blocked. I think that I'm approaching wrong to the solution. Maybe calling println from outside blocks as it doesn't have anywhere to print to.

I would like to understand what's happening and how could I solve this. My problem is using the output that creates the Class2 main from Class1.

I hope I explained well, I'm not a native speaker.

**EDIT**
Now I added more coding. I'm now realizing that waiting for the standard input maybe is interfering with the Print of the other class. Should I run an external proccess for the output? How could I do it on the same console view?

Comment: You should have a look at `Looging`.

Comment: so : obj.onMessage(new Message()); is not working ? I don't know "Message" so i don't now how it works

Comment: is the problem occurring when you try to create the Class1() object in main?

Comment: You should add the error message of console.

Comment: What do you mean by "the object seems to be blocked"? Also, what do you mean by "using the output that creates the Class2 main from Class1"? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The onmessage method is fires asynchronously when a JMS message is received. I have the problem when it is fired. I wait reading the input from the console.

Comment: Now I'm realizing that maybe the fact that I'm reading at the same time as writing is a bad idea... Should I wait for the input somehow so this doesn't happens? I didn't add the rest of the code for a quicker understanding

Answer (score 0):

try this
Class1.java

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;


public class Class1 {
       public static void main(String args[]) throws JMSException {
        Class2 obj = new Class2();
 Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
  Message m;
 TextMessage textMessage = null;

          System.out.println("Enter a message");

       textMessage.setText(s.next());

        m=(Message)textMessage;
 obj.onMessage(m);

    }
}
```

Class2.java

```
import javax.jms.*;

public class Class2 implements MessageListener{

public void onMessage(Message msg) {
        System.out.println(msg.toString());

        TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) msg;
        try {

            System.out.println(textMessage.getText());

        } catch (JMSException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The onMessage method fires when another Class is sending indeed a message. I'm going to upload my code as I didn't explained well on the first time

Comment: ok, waiting for your edit/code. and also for more information about JMS see this oracle java ee 6 tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnceh.html

Comment: I think my problem is more about managing In/Out than JMS (the rest of the application works fairly well). I updated my post. Thank you!

Comment: What is this Message Class? Is it belong to JMS or you created it by yourself??

Comment: It belongs to JMS indeed, my Class1 implements MessageListener from javax.jms. I use it for creating asynchronous messaging. 

This application is like a chat, you have the server and the clients. The clients send the message on the obj.anotherAction(action) and recieves them when other client sends their messages.

Comment: ok, now see the edited anwser , may be you can get some helpful stuff.

Comment: I finally solved the problem. I was blocking the input with some methods I didn't show on the code. Next time I'll copy everything instead of re-writing it trying to make it clear.... Thanks anyway, your post helped me solving the problem as it made me think on how I managed the in/out before the println.

Comment: @Davidaz No Problem. It is pleasure to help you and to hear that your problem is solved now by yourself.